# Filter rows by comparing two columns looker studio

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I am using a looker studio table chart which has a following structure

| Date time | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 27, 2024, 8:22:11 PM | 561 |
| Jan 26, 2024, 7:09:19 PM | 561 |
| Jan 26, 2024, 5:03:15 PM | 561 |
| Jan 24, 2024, 6:01:45 PM | 452 |
| Jan 24, 2024, 5:03:15 PM | 452 |
| Jan 24, 2024, 4:08:34 PM | 452 |
| Jan 23, 2024, 3:11:54 PM | 111 |
| Jan 23, 2024, 2:34:45 PM | 613 |

Here the date time is in descending order. I want an output which looks something like this.

| Date time | Code |
| --- | --- |
| Jan 27, 2024, 8:22:11 PM | 561 |
| Jan 24, 2024, 6:01:45 PM | 452 |
| Jan 23, 2024, 3:11:54 PM | 111 |
| Jan 23, 2024, 2:34:45 PM | 613 |

Here I would want the **Code** column to be unique and the **Date time** value associated with the Code to be latest.

I am new to looker studio not sure how to get this done.

Comment: Think about your table data ... it feels like what you want to do is group by "Code" and select MAX(Date Time).  In Looker Studio you can create multiple "Data Sources" in a dashboard.  My immediate thought is to create a 2nd data source from your table where there is custom SQL run against that Data Source as described above and then you visualize the results of that second data source.